# What does it mean to add two linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I can't make a kind of intuition why an addition of two equations remains a system the same. I try to develope geometrical intuition behind this.

For this I just think of each of equations in the following manner. Let there be an equation $x + 2y = 3$. And assume variables $x$ and $y$ represent number of hours for some entertainment, where coefficients are prices per hour. So the price of first entertainment is $1\$$ per hour, and $2\$$ is a price of second one per hour. And totally I can only spend $3\$$. So this basically gives me a line, the points on which give me possible solutions.

Let now there be another equation that represents same entertainments in another city. $3x+y=5$. So prices here are different.

Then I wonder how many dollars I can totally spend for entertainments in both cities? This is, of course, $3\$+5\$=8\$$. This means I should also add left sides (I can't understand why. I mean geometrically). Then it gives me another equation $(x+2y) + (3x+y) = 4x + 3y = 8$. Using the same interpretation it appears that the price of the entertainment suddenly changes to $4\$$ and of second to $3\$$. Why should the price change? Can you please explain what is the meaning of addition of two lines and why they remain the system the same?

Comment: The flaw in your reasoning is that in a system, $x$ and $y$ need to represent the same unknown in both equations. This is not the case in your model because $x$ represents an unknown number of hours in city A in the first equation and in city B in the second equation.

Comment: x and y are two variables. you can either consider one equation as a Diophantine equation and find many solutions or use another equation to find certain solutions but you can not add two equations, because , as you found you get a solution that does not satisfy each equations.

Comment: @Gribouillis hours of the same entertainments. Does this make sense?

Comment: @sirous I actually don't want to find any solutions. There can be infinite of them. I just want to know why this relation keeps the system the same

Comment: There is not infinite solution, there can  only be one solution for x and one for y in a system of equation.

Comment: @sirous yes. I just wanted to say that I am not interested in any solution, even if there are infinite of them. Never mind. Should I read about Diophantine equation to understand this?

Comment: The basic reason why the system remains the same is that you can recover the old system from the new system obtained by adding the two equations.

Comment: When you sum two equations in fact you consider total rate in two cities, in other words you suppose one place of entertainment with rates, 3 and 4 for certain hours which is the same hours in  each city.

Comment: @sirous, It may sound funny. But why not to take the maximum of rates instead of adding them? Because the maximum rate will already include the smaller one.

Comment: What you did means that!

Comment: @sirous sorry? I think I didn't get it